# How to perform a glob search on a previous directory

Tags: java, glob

I'm trying to write a java program which will take either the exact path or name of a file, or will take some form of pattern like a glob.  The internals of the program will just be repeated for every file which is found by the filepath specifier.

Here's an example of some of the paths I would expect to be able to enter:

```
example.txt
```

Processes 'example.txt' in the local directory.

```
*.txt
```

Processes all text files of the local directory.

```
../*
```

Processes all text files in the previous directory.

It's this last one that I'm having a lot of trouble with.  I can get the first two to work by using a PathMatcher, but I can't get it to emulate the ../ without scanning essentially the whole drive which the program is running in.

I'm having a ton of trouble getting pattern matching to work.  I just want it to work in a similar fashion to grep, where I can either use it to specify an exact file, or a pattern of files.

Are there any examples of this being done?

Comment: Why don't you just chdir to the previous directory for every '..' that appears in the path?

Comment: I don't at all see the point in this. The shell already does perfectly what you're trying your program to teach - just iterate through the `args` array in your `main`-method.

Comment: @daniu does it work exactly the same on linux and windows?

Comment: @Andy mostly... but the differences are pretty much exactly the reason you should leave it to the shell and just expect a list of files - that you'll get on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @daniu I've gone with that solution, works fine for me.  You don't have to, but if you want to write it up as an answer I will mark it as answered (and you can have the points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, I'll take the points :D  Also, someone might Google this and will have an easier time using an "accepted" answer.

The shell does this for you, and most probably less error-prone than what you are trying to do manually.

```
private static void main(String[] files) {
    for (String file : files) {
        process(file);
    }
}
```

This will work on all systems I'm aware of for pretty much all globbing you'll ever come across.